# Generic query with interface as a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

So I've been fighting against generics lately and don't quite know how to solve this one.

Basically I have a generic query framework defined as `IRxQuery<T>` . My basic model follows one rule: T needs to be an instance type. Here is the implementation header:

```
public class RxQuery<T> : IRxQuery<T>
        where T : IQueryableObject
```

One of the notable methods in this class is the `Get` method, which will deserialize the object got by the query into a T object. The method kinda looks like that:

```
    protected virtual T Get(IDeserializableObject row)
    {
        var value = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        // fill value 

        return value;
    }
```

Now, I would like to upgrade my query so it would be working with an interface. I am facing the current problem: I have an `ISomething` interface, implemented by `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`. I'd have a case where the query could be any of them and I am trying to fix it, without going adding inheritance. So I was trying something like:

```
IRxQuery<ISomething> query;
if (isObjectA)
{
   query = new RxQuery<ObjectA>();
}
else
{
   query = new RxQuery<ObjectB>();
}
```

And of course, you know that won't compile. The only solution I thought about so far would be to add a property to the `IRxQuery` type looking like:

```
public Type InstanceType{ get; set; }
```

And then update the Get method to this:

```
protected virtual T Get(IDeserializableObject row)
{
   T value = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(InstanceType))
}
```

What approach would you advise me to use to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `IRxQuery` look like? Could you make `T` covariant?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to make this work:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //compile error: ISomething must be non-abstract with public
        //               parameterless constructor
        RxQuery<ISomething> something = new RxQuery<ISomething>();
    }
}
interface ISomething { };
interface IRxQuery<T> { }
public class RxQuery<T> : IRxQuery<T> where T:new() /*, IDeserializableObject*/ {
    //Factory Method Pattern
    protected virtual T Get(/*IDeserializableObject row*/) { return new T(); }
}
```

`Get` is a factory method and cannot instantiate an interface using `new()`. Even if you made `T` covariant (`IRxQuery<out T>`), you're no closer to it working. Your proposed solution of using `Activator.CreateInstance` (reflection) and having the Type information returned from `IRxQuery` might work, but regardless it's a poor solution in my opinion (it forfeits some compile-time checks, and requires reflection (obfuscation, if ever needed, could cause this code to crash)).

If `T` must be able to be an `interface`, then my suggestion is to find a new design such that `RxQuery<T>` does not need to construct an object of type `T`.